# Any way to prevent getUserMedia "Live Broadcast" when applied to a video srcObject inside WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm having some issues with the now available getUserMedia api available in the WKWebView (as of iOS 14.3).

On a page in the webview, I will access the camera using the following code:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
        facingMode: "user"
    },
    audio: false
}).then(function(webcamStream) {
    document.querySelector("#video").srcObject = webcamStream; /* this is a HTML video tag available on the page */
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("fail")
});
```

This... mostly works. Unlike in Safari (and now Chrome), instead of the video element just showing what is in the video track of the `webcamStream` MediaStream object, it opens up a "Live Broadcast" panel and the video track pauses whenever this is closed. Is there anyway to replicate the behaviour in Safari and Chrome, where there is no panel popup?

[Image of the "Live Broadcast" panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Kew.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Safari iOS web based apps, link: [Video Playback on Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari)  references that the  element needs to have a playsInLine attribute along with the idea that it won't autoplay unless it is muted and it pauses if it is out of frame. `<video id="video" autoplay playsInline muted></video>` and the stream may need to *stream*.play() to get it started.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari

As for recording, https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/ has info for the MediaRecorder interface available in Safari 14.03?  I don't have much info for native iOS apps.

Comment: Hi, yes it was a matter of playsInline not being on the video element! Thank you for your  response.

Comment: I have the `playsInline` prop on `<video>` but it opens up Live Broadcast anyway :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution. You have to set these properties on [WKWebViewConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration)
 to true:

- [allowsInlineMediaPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614793-allowsinlinemediaplayback)
- [mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor)

Then video will play as expected